# Selenium message:stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I want to extract links of hits from google search with Rselenium. I cannot get past this error, can somebody point out what I am doing wrong, how to solve this? 
Example:

```
library("RSelenium")    
google <- "https://www.google.com"    
driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"),chromever = "78.0.3904.105")    
remote <- driver$client    
remote$navigate(google)    
google_query <- remote$findElement("name","q")    
google_query$sendKeysToElement(sendKeys = list('error stackoverflow'))    
google_query$submitElement()    
results <- google_query$findElements(using = "class",value = "iUh30")    
link <- results[[1]]    
link <- link$getElementText()
## here i was expecting url
```

Error:

```
Selenium message:stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'

Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: StaleElementReference
     Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Thanks.

EDIT: To clarify problem. The results are not empyt, I got back the list of the DOM elememts, but when I am trying to access text in them I got the error above.